WSL- System cannot find file... Wsl/Service/CreateInstance
When I open Ubuntu I got the message:
wsl: The system cannot find the path specified.
Error code: CreateInstance/CreateVm/ConfigureNetworking/ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND
wsl: Failed to configure network (networkingMode Bridged), falling back to no networking.
ping: google.com: Temporary failure in name resolution
ping 8.8.8.8 ping: connect: Network is unreachable
suggestions what to do? I tried to reinstall and unregister its not worked
(I want to run this lines but not working too: sudo apt-get update
sudo apt install build-essential cmake gdb valgrind)
